# Django Create Temporary File for Download

Tags: django

I have a model named `ReportData`. I have a form which will get 'report_name' and will perform an operation. This operation basically loops through objects, every object returned has a file field having a '.docx' file, this function will merge all these files into one docx file.

After this, `convert()` method will convert 'docx' to 'pdf'. I am able to perform this workflow but I need to create a temporary file instead of real files in media directory. My class-based view is below:

```
class FilesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = ReportData
    template_name = 'report/myfiles.html'
    context_object_name = 'reportdata'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ReportData.objects.filter(preparedby=self.request.user).order_by('-date_created')

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        filtervalue = request.POST.get("report_name","")
        reportsforPDF = ReportData.objects.filter(reportname=filtervalue)
        reporturl = settings.MEDIA_ROOT[0:-6]
        master = Document(reporturl + reportsforPDF.first().document.url)
        composer = Composer(master)
        i=0
        for object in reportsforPDF:
            if i>0:
                doc = Document(reporturl + object.document.url)
                composer.append(doc)
            i+=1
        storage = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/merged/{}.docx'.format(filtervalue)
        composer.save(storage)
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        convert(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/merged/{}.docx'.format(filtervalue))
        context = {
            'pdf_url': '/media/merged/{}.pdf'.format(filtervalue)
        }
        return render(request, 'report/myfiles.html', context=context)
```

Also how can I use `get_queryset` inside the post function because my current code returns no objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tempfile` module

Here is the basic example:

```
import os
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
f.write("Hello World")
f.seek(os.SEEK_SET)

# Do something
f.read()
# Do something

f.close() # Deletes
```

You can use below line in `post` method:
`_queryset = self.get_queryset()`

Comment: When should I call f.close() as I am passing the 'pdf_url' as context

Comment: file should persist right? in order to get access to the file file should not be deleted I guess.

Comment: Not sure about the context, correct me if I am wrong.